# Passing a delimited string in the NOT IN clause

Tags: oracle, plsql

The below SQL conceptually replicates the problem I'm trying to solve.  Despite passing a NOT IN clause all three records are returned.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 'JACK' AS VALUE FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'JOHN' AS VALUE FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'BOB' AS VALUE FROM DUAL
) WHERE VALUE NOT IN (SELECT 'BOB,JOHN' FROM DUAL);
```

I have a table that holds a delimited string that I want to use as the criteria to exclude records from the dataset.  However, the problem I have is that the returned string is not broken down into its delimited items.  I want the above to translate to:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 'JACK' AS VALUE FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'JOHN' AS VALUE FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'BOB' AS VALUE FROM DUAL
) WHERE VALUE NOT IN ('BOB','JOHN');
```

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:210612357425

Comment: You have a table that holds a delimited string? Why? If you used your database properly and stored the strings separately, there would be no problem writing a query.

Comment: All three records are returned because `'BOB,JOHN'` is a **single string value**. Clearly `'BOB,JOHN' != 'BOB'` and `'BOB,JOHN' != 'JACK'` and `'BOB,JOHN' != 'JOHN'`. So the result is correct. The issue is that you are storing a collection as a string rather than something more fitted, such as an array or a table.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments and totally agree.  I would have used a table to hold values, but in the company I'm working for have adopted this approach hence why I'm having to work the way described in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regexp_substr for that problem:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT 'JACK' AS VALUE FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'JOHN' AS VALUE FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'BOB' AS VALUE FROM DUAL
)
WHERE VALUE NOT IN (SELECT regexp_substr('BOB,JOHN','[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) FROM dual CONNECT BY regexp_substr('BOB,JOHN', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Posting a block of code and saying "use this" is not the best help without an explanation of what the problem with the OP's code was and an explanation of why (and how) your code solves the problem.

Comment: And where does that start and end? Does he know what a substr is? Does he know what regular expressions are and how they are used. Does he know what connect by is? If he has any further questions he can ask them and I'm willing to help. But I'd have a hard time guessing what more information he needs.

Answer (score 1):

`'BOB,JOHN'` is not a list of two string values it is one string value that just happens to contain a comma in the string and:

```
'JACK' = 'BOB,JOHN'
'JOHN' = 'BOB,JOHN'
'BOB'  = 'BOB,JOHN'
```

Are all false so your query will return all rows as matched by the `NOT IN` filter.

You can surround your values and list with the delimiter characters and test whether the value is not a sub-string of the list like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 'JACK' AS VALUE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JOHN' AS VALUE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'BOB'  AS VALUE FROM DUAL
)
WHERE INSTR( ',' || 'BOB,JOHN' || ',', ',' || value || ',' ) = 0
```

Or you can use a user-defined collection:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
```

Then use the `MEMBER OF` operator to test whether a value is a member of the collection:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 'JACK' AS VALUE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JOHN' AS VALUE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'BOB'  AS VALUE FROM DUAL
)
WHERE  VALUE NOT MEMBER OF StringList( 'BOB', 'JOHN' );
```